# Java Reflection, extract generic type from method

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a java method with the following signature:

```
static <ContentType> Map<Object,ContentType> foo();
```

I want to use reflection to dynamically change the behavior of the method according to `ContentType`.
To achieve this, I must be able to handle `ContentType` as an object (maybe an instance of java.lang.reflect.Type).
Does anyone know how to do this? Is that event possible?

Comment: it will not be possible before java 9 because of type erasure.

Comment: The only way to do this is by adding an argument: static <ContentType> Map<Object,ContentType> foo(Class<ContentType> type);

Comment: or, of course, testing the content of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Generics in Java are "syntactic sugar". They are only used at compile-time but are then removed and never make it into the class file.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) has some realy good information on this.

Comment: Note : It will probably be possible from Java 9.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Why do you say it will be possible in Java 9? If you're talking about the generic changes included as part of the [value types proposal](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169), that is currently targeted for Java 10 (and is very far from completion, so this might not end up being possible).

Comment: @PhilAnderson It is called `reification` and as says Toby, it is not clear whether it will be ready for Java 9 or Java 10. https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/the_javaone_2013_technical_keynote

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle From my understanding full reification is no longer a goal ([JEP 218: Generics over Primitive Types](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046267)), although this could of course change.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself, like java.util.List, there is no way of knowing what type is has been parameterized to. But, when you inspect the method that declares the use of a parameterized type, you can see at runtime what type the parameterizable type was parameterized to

```
Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("getStringList", null);

Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
if(returnType instanceof ParameterizedType){
  ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
  Type[] typeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();
  for(Type typeArgument : typeArguments){
      Class typeArgClass = (Class) typeArgument;
      System.out.println("typeArgClass = " + typeArgClass);
  }
}
```